How does Prolog "redo" search when backtracking
I think that I understand how Prolog uses unification and backtracking to find the first match. However I'm having a hard time trying to understand what does it do when it is asked to "redo" the search, e.g. when using ; in REPL, or findall. I'm trying to understand how the search is implemented, but most of the discussions on this topic stop on saying that it "marks" the last successful node and continues search from there, but this is a bit vague for me.
Could someone share a more detailed resource, or even better, an explanation with a pseudocode, of an algorithm that goes back to the node on the search tree and resumes the search from there. What kind of history does it need to keep to do this?

Did you already read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking and this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search? You could also consider reading the source of one of the open-source Prolog implementations.

@TA_intern Yes I did. As for the source code, eventually, I will but I want to have a high-level overview first. Actual implementations usually have many implementation details irrelevant to the general algorithm and you need to filter them out.

OK, then, which part of depth-first traversal are you struggling with?

Disclaimer: I am not an artificial intelligence tool. I am a biological entity and just a tool. I will prove this by not answering your question.

There is something about your question that is worth discussing. It is not the algorithm, the algorithm for backtracking can be found implemented in many familiar languages, from C to Python to Haskell. You should be able to find enough by just searching.
This last sentence:

What kind of history does it need to keep to do this?

No history, really. The nodes of the solution tree contain the state of the solution; you just need to keep a reference to the last node that still has sub-trees that have not been yet visited.
This is also one of the most annoying properties of Prolog. Once you backtrack "up" the tree (closer to the root...) you throw away all state that is in the sub-trees that were already visited. If those had solutions, you will lose the solutions, too.
Example in Prolog:
?- (X = a ; X = b).
X = a ;
X = b.

You get your first solution, you press Space (or ;); at this point, your first solution X = a is gone. It is no more. Unless you use a side-effect to somehow save it, you can no longer access it.

The "potentially recursive and infinite" remark. One example of non-recursive but still non-terminating query:
?- length(List, N), N =< 3.

The length/2 predicate will generate lists with increasing length. The comparison will fail if the list is over 3 long. You should try it out.
And here is a recursive non-terminating query:
?- List = [a|List], append(List, [one_more], Result).

You have a circular list, and you try to append something to its end. But it has no end...

The problem I have is that the search tree here is potentially recursive and infinite. It’s fairly easy to traverse for the first match for the goal, but I have hard time understanding how the history of visited nodes is represented as you need to know how not to backtrack to the node you already visited.

@Tim Yes, it is potentially recursive and infinite. This is another annoying property of Prolog, how easy it is to get into "non-termination" with the simplest programs. See my edit for that.

@Tim you say, "but I have hard time understanding how the history of visited nodes is represented". There is no history. There might be a stack of "yet not-expanded nodes". You have those when you have a node in the solution tree with multiple child nodes. In depth-first traversal, you will expand the first child and push to the stack the reference to this node, so that once you are done with the sub-tree of the first child you can continue from the sibling. PLEASE google for "Prolog proof search". Example
